# Dynamically retrieving current method's name

Tags: objective-c

I'd like to be able to put trace messages of the current class name and method name for all classes in my project.

Is there a way to get the current method's name at run time, similar to:

```
NSLog(@"classname: %@", [self className]);
```

where self is a class derived out of NSObject?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
NSLog(@"method name: %@", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
```

`_cmd` is a hidden argument (like `self`) that all Objective-C methods receive. Its value is the selector that was used to call the method.

Comment: i utilize SEL myRunTimeSelector = _cmd. Thanks

Comment: Proper solution including explanations. Thanks.

Answer (score 18):

EDITED:
i think this method is more generic...check it out..

```
NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
```

Comment: my apologies if i come out as condescending, didnt mean to... I found this solution to be more generic...

Comment: great answer. i put it into a macro, like this:
#define LOGME NSLog(@"%s", \_\_PRETTY_FUNCTION\_\_);

Comment: Great Answer @Nishant ..  It is giving both the class name and the method name for good debugging...

Comment: great,this macro help me a lot,it give more comprehensive information about current class and method to be called

Comment: Nice trick but it provides not only the method's name but also the class name it belongs to which is not really what Alexi Groove initially wanted. The solution of Chuck including '_cmd' is the best one in my view.

Answer (score 1):

This also works:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithUTF8String:__func__])
```