# Is there a preprocessor macro that expands to the current selector?

Tags: objective-c, c-preprocessor, predefined-macro

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dynamically retrieving current method's name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457555/dynamically-retrieving-current-methods-name)
>   [Obj-C introspection: How can a method reference it's own selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8431498/obj-c-introspection-how-can-a-method-reference-its-own-selector)

This applies to Objective-C, is there a preprocessor macro or something to get the SEL value of the current selector? Specifically I'm looking for something like:

```
-(void) someSelector
{
    SEL mySelector = __CURRENT_SELECTOR__;
    NSLog(@"I'm in selector %@",NSStringFromSelector(mySelector));
}
```

it's kinda like the `__FILE__` macro but this to obtain the current selector. Pretty useful to pass it to others while not worrying to update it if the selector name is changed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Every method has two implicit parameters, `self` which is an `id` (the receiver) and a `SEL` called `_cmd`, which is probably what you want.

Note that this has nothing to do with preprocessor or anything before compile-time, `_cmd` is not a macro, it's an argument.

```
-(void) someSelector
{
    NSLog(@"I'm in selector %@",NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

What sidyll said should answer your question. Just wanted to add if you just need it for logging you can also use the usual C keywords, e.g.

```
NSLog( @"%s" , __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSLog( @"%s" , _cmd );
```

_cmd will get you the current selector(only available in objective-c)